# Call Web Service via crm workflow

Tags: web, plugins, service, workflow, crm

Currently i'm working on a crm project. In this project i have to send data to web service and take refined data back. This operation must be work on custom workflow but i'm stuck infact i have no idea how to do it? Any suggestions?

```
Here is my service code; 


var tmpIncident = getIncidentById(organizationServiceContext);
        if (tmpIncident != null) //if we have decent incident we connect service and proceed the data.
        {
            GetCustomerInfoService.TransactionServiceClient client = new GetCustomerInfoService.TransactionServiceClient();
            GetCustomerInfoService.TransactionRequest request = new GetCustomerInfoService.TransactionRequest();


            #region authentication  
            request.AuthenticationData.UserName = "user";
            request.AuthenticationData.Password = "pass";
            #endregion

            Guid id = Guid.NewGuid(); //create random guid
            request.RequestId = id.ToString();
            request.OrderNumber = tmpIncident.vrp_ordernumber;

            GetCustomerInfoService.TransactionResponse response = client.GetTransactionByOrderNumber(request);
            tmpIncident.CustomerId = new EntityReference("Contact", new Guid(response.Message));


            this.updateChanges(organizationServiceContext, tmpIncident);

            client.Close();
        }
```

When i tested plugin, i received that error;

> Error Message:

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'GetCustomerInfoService.ITransactionService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
   at Vrp.Crm.PluginLibrary2013.GetCustomerInfoService.TransactionServiceClient..ctor() in :line 0
   at Vrp.Crm.PluginLibrary2013.CustomWorkflows.SetCumstomerIdToIncident.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) in c:\Veripark\Projects\gisik\DRCRM.VERITOUCH.CRM2013\PluginLibrary2013\CustomWorkflows\CheckSubIncidentForMainIncident.cs:line 72
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Comment: You need to send to the service the path where the config file is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Dynamics CRM. This is a high-level overview:

1. Create a custom workflow activity that makes the actual call to the webservice. This should help you get started: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328515.aspx
2. The custom activity would have output parameters that would return the results from the webservice back to the calling CRM workflow.
3. Finally create the workflow and its triggers that would make use of your custom activity. More info: 
   http://crmbook.powerobjects.com/system-administration/processes/workflows/
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328264.aspx

I hope this is enough information to get you heading down the right path.

Comment: Yes, i already trying to do this actually, thing is i can not connect web service?

Comment: I am confused, are you referring to an external web service or the Dynamics CRM web service?

Comment: external web service

Comment: What have you tried? What error are you receiving? May I suggest, testing out you web service call within a simple console application to make sure everything works fine and then moving it to custom activity.